# How to get Active Directory domain objectGUID anonymously

Tags: active-directory, ldap, windows

As an authenticated Active Directory user, I can run this to get the domain GUID (objectGUID):

```
dsquery * "DC=lab,DC=local" -scope base -attr objectguid
```

I can use this command in Linux to get the domain (lab.local) SID from the domain controller labdc01 without an account (anonymously):

```
# rpcclient -U% labdc01.lab.local -c lsaquery
Domain Name: LAB 
Domain Sid: S-1-5-21-3869872838-1836277878-698564084
```

If I know the GUID, I can fetch it from DNS:

> _ldap._tcp.4f904480-7c78-11cf-b057-00aa006b4f8f.domains._msdcs.lab.local.

How can I get the domain objectGUID anonymously (like the SID example above)?

Answer (score 6):

By default:

### You can't

With Active Directory, for any anynymous LDAP operation (apart from RootDSE binds) to succeed, you would need to:

1. [Enable anonymous binds](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/326690)
2. [Allow Anonymous access to public properties](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/320528)

Comment: Thank you! Then I know that it is not possible via LDAP. Your reply excludes other options. Theoretically it is possible via DNS. You can get the SID without LDAP (with lsaquery) anonymously.